# Python-how to print multiple rows with a common word from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

```
 whichgender=input("Would you like to view male or female students? ")
 if whichgender == "Male":
    with open('classinfo.csv' , 'r') as classinfoReport:
        classinfoReaders = csv.reader(classinfoReport)
        for row in classinfoReaders:
            for field in row:
               if field == whichgender:
                  print (row)
```

I am trying to print every row from my csv file that contains the word 'Male'. This code works but it only prints the first row that it finds with the word Male in . There are 13 rows in my file with 'Male' in them and I want to print them all.How do I do that??

Comment: Please provide few lines of the input for example, it would help find whats wrong with your code

Comment: If my suggestion solved your problem, marking it as the answer would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `pandas` to simplify the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('classinfo.csv', header=None))
print(df[df[<index of the gender string here>] == 'Male'])
```

I wrote a dummy CSV file with the same filename as yours `classinfo.csv`:

```
Adam,Male,25
Milo,Male,34
Mikka,Female,20
Samantha,Female,19
John,Male,21
```

Since the gender index is `1`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('classinfo.csv', header=None))
print(df[df[1] == 'Male'])
```

The result when run:

```
      0     1   2
0  Adam  Male  25
1  Milo  Male  34
4  John  Male  21
```

Answer (score 0):

OR you can change the following in your code as

```
whichgender=input("Would you like to view male or female students? ")
 if whichgender == "Male":
    with open('classinfo.csv' , 'r') as classinfoReport:
        classinfoReaders = csv.reader(classinfoReport)
        for row in classinfoReaders:
            if 'Male' in row:
                print(row)
```

My suggestion is also to use `pandas`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:-

```
 whichgender=input("Would you like to view male or female students? ")
 if whichgender == "Male":
    with open('classinfo.csv' , 'r') as classinfoReport:
        classinfoReaders = csv.reader(classinfoReport)
        for row in classinfoReaders:
            for field in row:
               if whichgender in field:
                  print (row)
```